# Get all information of a facebook page

Tags: json, access-token, facebook-page

I would like to recover the non-public information to a facebook page for an application "desktop" in C # and I do not know how. Do I have to go through a Facebook application that the user allow or do I get the Facebook user to have a access_token and display the page based on this one? FYI I use graph (and a JSON) that I get, I picked up this version as the "public" group:
https://graph.facebook.com/283774678311430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to go through a Facebook application that the user allow

Yes, you need an application to let the user give access to view the page or have the page owner give access

> do I get the Facebook user to have a access_token and display the page based on this one?

Same answer, use the page owner as the user call `/me/accounts` and grab the page access token.